# why am I getting error when I am assigning value of a pointer sent by parameter to a local pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ref(int *a,int *b) {
    int *t;
    *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *t;
}

int main() {
    int a = 2, b = 3;
    ref(&a, &b);
    printf("a=%d,b=%d", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages sometime.  When you ask a question about an error, you should provide more detail about the error — is it a compiler error or a run-time error; what is the message you get, etc.  That's a part of the process of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) — explaining what goes wrong precisely and concisely.

Comment: Within your function `ref`, `a` and `b` point to other variables actually defind in the calling function, `main`.  But where does `t` point?  And what exactly do the lines `*t = *a` and `*b = *t` do?

Comment: I know it can be done easily by defining the func in the way given below.bt i want to know why the above code is note working.void ref(int *a,int *b){
    int t;
    t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;
}

Comment: Jonathan Leffler,the error displayed is segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @NIKITAAGARWAL You are accessing the t without defining memory, same is answered below.

Comment: Steve Summit,does *t=*a not assign the value of pointer a to t.I did this to assign the value stored at the address of a to value at t.Is it the wrong way?

Comment: Thanks.I have understood my mistake now.I am trying to assign value at pointer t,which is not holding address of any variable.

Comment: @NIKITAAGARWAL No, `*t=*a` absolutely does *not* assign the value of the pointer `a` to the pointer `t`.  (Nor is that what you want to do in this case.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> why am I getting error when I am assigning value of a pointer sent by parameter to a local pointer in C

I am not sure what do you mean by the error. Is it a segmentation fault or some unexpected behaviour of your swapping function? To answer your question in short, you have been `deferencing` an `uninitialised pointer` and it is the cause of unexpected behaviour of your program.

The local pointer `t` declared in your function `ref` has `automatic` [storage class](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/C/Storage_Classes).

All variables declared in C within a block of code (in your case, in funcction `ref`) has automatic storage class by
default. An uninitialised automatic variable has an undefined value
until it is assigned a valid value of its type.

So, your pointer `t` has undefined value and will be storing some garbage value. You can try printing the value of your pointer `t`.

```
printf("Value of the pointer is %p\r\n", t);
```

To use a pointer in C, to store values and retrieve values (dereferencing) from them, the pointer variable should be pointing to a `valid memory location`. Otherwise, you will get unexpected behaviour and your program may crash with a segmentation fault.

To make sure, variable `t` points to a particular valid memory location, you can use one of the two alternatives.

Using a variable with automatic storage class.

```
void ref(int *a, int *b)
{
    int t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

Using dynamically allocated memory location

```
void ref(int *a, int *b)
{
    int *t = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = *t;

    free(t); // Free the memory allocated dynamically
 }
```

The former method using an `automatic variable` (int t;) suits your requirement and will be efficient approach for your application. However, I have still mentioned a method using a pointer allocated dynamically to give you a glimpse of using a pointer.

Comment: *Using statically allocated variable.*  I'm afraid you mean *Using a variable with automatic storage*

Comment: Good. but while your answer has mostly correct contents, it does not pin down the correct solution with enough clarity. Using an allocated block of memory for the purpose of this `ref` (better renamed as `swap`) function is not good advice for the OP. Not my DV but other answers are simpler and more pertinent IMHO.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more clearer and pointing the correct solution.

Comment: You would have to be one sandwich short of a picnic to use the malloc / free approach for t.

Answer (score 6):

`int* t;` merely declares a pointer to an `int`; but `t` does not point to an `int` (unlike `a` and `b` which do).

Hence the behaviour of `*t` is *undefined*.

In your particular case, `int t;` would suffice, with subsequent code changed to `t = *a` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.I have understood it now

Comment: @NIKITAAGARWAL **If one of the asnwers is helpful, accept it by clicking tick below number on the left side**

Answer (score 6):

`int *t;` declaring pointer like this will not create any memory means `t` is pointing to nothing, accessing `*t = *a;` will give undefined behavior.
In your case you don't need pointer to swap two variables you just need normal variable.

```
void ref(int *a,int *b){    
   int t;
   t=*a;
   *a=*b;
   *b=t;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation